# Google crawler and browser language detection

Tags: language, multilingual, configuration

I have just experienced something weird with the language filter in combination with the Google crawler.

If I switch on browser detection, Joomla returns a 404 (I assume, because no "ALL language" article is present), as the crawler has no language preference.
I thought, the default language would be used in such a case.

Haven't found a solution yet, to get the same behaviour as when access is made by a visitor through a browser.

How do you handle this?

Comment: I can't answer your question, but this link has come in handy viewing a link in the same way that the search engine bots do:  http://aw-snap.info/file-viewer/

Answer (score 2):

Have you set up your site to be multilingual - i.e. separate menu for each language with corresponding and linked articles?  What settings do you have on the multilingual side of things - e.g. the language filter plugin?

I'm not sure if this article helps: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192?hl=en#1

If your site is properly set up to use multilingual and is working, I wouldn't worry too much about what happens when you're trying to crawl as Google, unless you're seeing errors in Webmaster Tools?